# <c:when> with multiple condtion fail?

Tags: jsf, jstl, el

I have more than one test condition in `<c:when/>`

```
<c:forEach items="#{managedBean.genericFeaturesListEquips}"
 var="genFeatCapacity" varStatus="genericFeatCapIndex">
    <c:when test="${not empty genFeatCapacity.minLength &amp;&amp; genFeatCapacity.minLength > 0 }">
    <h:inputText value="min_#{genFeatCapacity.minLength}"/>
    </c:when>
</c:forEach>
```

and i am getting value in inputtextbox is `min_`

As you can check `minLength` is Integer variable and value is empty,but why the condition is fail and its printing `min_` ?

Comment: Is the `#{genFeatCapacity}` defined by `var="genFeatCapacity"` of an iterator component?

Comment: @BalusC I am using  `c:forEach `

Comment: @SubodhJoshi: Please learn to make an [mcve] when asking questions. Saves us asking all kinds of questions. See also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: @BalusC Sorry its my mistake i did not added   `<c:choose/>`